# How to encode the subject of the mail in Powershell?

Tags: email, powershell, character-encoding, smtp

I am trying to send mail using Powershell with Japanese character on the subject and body of the mail. The mail is successfully sent and the Japanese character in the body is fine. But it is not working in subject. I got `=?iso-2022-jp?Q?=1B=24B=25F=259=25H=1B=28B?=` instead of `テスト`.

Can someone help me on this?

**code**:

```
$eSubject = "テスト This is subject"
$eBody = "テスト テスト テスト This is body"

$Encode = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("csISO2022JP");
$s64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Encode.GetBytes($eSubject), [Base64FormattingOptions]::None)

$Mail = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage("From@mail.com","To@mail.com")
$Mail.Subject = [String]::Format("=?{0}?B?{1}?=", $Encode.HeaderName, $s64)

$View = [Net.Mail.AlternateView]::CreateAlternateViewFromString($eBody, $Encode, [Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames]::Text.Plain)
$View.TransferEncoding = [Net.Mime.TransferEncoding]::SevenBit
$Mail.AlternateViews.Add($View)

$SmtpClient = NEW-OBJECT Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost","25")
$SmtpClient.Send($Mail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how. But it is working now, I just remove the encoding for subject.

**code**:

```
$eSubject = "テスト This is subject"
$eBody = "テスト テスト テスト This is body"

$Encode = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("csISO2022JP");

$Mail = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage("From@mail.com","To@mail.com")
$Mail.Subject = $eSubject

$View = [Net.Mail.AlternateView]::CreateAlternateViewFromString($eBody, $Encode, [Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames]::Text.Plain)
$View.TransferEncoding = [Net.Mime.TransferEncoding]::SevenBit
$Mail.AlternateViews.Add($View)

$SmtpClient = NEW-OBJECT Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost","25")
$SmtpClient.Send($Mail)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the default CmdLet `Send-MailMessage` it works fine for me:

```
$EmailParams = @{
    To          = 'Destination@domain.com'
    From        = 'From@domain.com'
    Subject     = 'テスト This is the subject'
    Body        = 'テスト This is the body'
    SMTPServer  = 'YourSMTPServer'
    Encoding    = 'UTF8'
}
Send-MailMessage @EmailParams
```